# Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '}' functions.php linha 1

Tags: php, wordpress

Estou com uma instalação wordpress funcionando em um outro servidor e localmente, porém, quando subi para outro host recebi o seguinte erro:

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '}' in
>   /home/khoru270/public_html/wp-content/themes/u-design/functions.php on
>   line 1

Já verifiquei várias vezes e não encontro onde essa chave estaria. E como disse está funcionando em outros dois locais.

Segue o código:
http://pastebin.com/P1nTWDSV

Comment: O código no pastebin não apresenta erros, qual versão do PHP está utilizando no servidor que apresenta o erro?

Comment: Qual a versao do php no teu servidor? Poste o conteudo do /home/khoru270/public_html/wp-content/themes/u-design/functions.php ... O problema me parece um erro de digitacao, mas tambem pode ser um erro com conversao de caracteres.

Comment: A versão do PHP é a 5.2 Bruno

Comment: O código está no link do pastebin

Comment: Renato, desculpa, mas não vou ler 3200 linhas de código pra procurar o erro pra você. Sem chance. Se você diz que o mesmo tema funciona em outros locais, quase que certamente o erro não está nesse arquivo. Se desligar **todos** os plugins, dá o mesmo erro?

Comment: Não acredito que haja um erro nesse código, pelo menos não um erro de sintaxe, mesmo colocando um die(); na primeira linha ele continua apresentando o mesmo erro.

Comment: Provavelmente o problema e por ser a versao 5.2 e no seu computador deve estar usando uma versao mais recente, recomendo que atualize no servidor pois a versao 5.2 esta bem obsoleta. Recomendo versao 5.4+.

Answer (score 2):

Depois de quase enlouquecer descobri o problema. Parece que o Filezilla estava corrompendo o arquivo.

No filezilla fui em editar>configurações>transferências>tipos de arquivo> e mudar do automático para binário. Reiniciei o filezilla e subi o arquivo novamente.

Agradeço a todos que me deram uma força, vlw mesmo pessoal.